# How to remove audio device from Preferences?

Tags: audio, preferences

I'm trying to remove an old device from the Sound Preferences pane. The app is trashed along with whatever preference files I could find. But it remains after reboot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate Devices are accessed from Applications/Utilities/Audio Midi Setup.

You can select & remove it from there.

Individual components will be added/removed as you install/uninstall them, but the Aggregate itself will remain until removed manually, as it contains **all** available sources.
The same is true of Multi-Output devices.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but this make no sense. Why you can't remove it form the Settings/Sound UI!

Comment: @KamilDzieniszewski - Because it's not designed for that at all. You can't add it from there either. You can only add/remove aggregate & Multi-output devices from Audio MIDI Setup. I added a bit more explanation.